# How to upload video on youtube on a specific channel using Xamarin forms for Android and iOS both?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms, youtube-api

Is there any way to upload video on youtube on a specific channel using Xamarin forms for Android and iOS both?

Answer (score 2):

The youtube api has a method called [Videos.insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert)

This is a HTTP Post Request

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos
```

Xamarin forms has the ability to preform HTTP POsts against Rest APIs.  [Consume a RESTful web service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/web-services/rest)

So I would say yes there is a way to upload videos to YouTube using Xamarin.  However that being said the Google .net client library does not support Xamarin login.  You will need to code the login yourself but that's doable I did it a few years ago and it only took me a few days to workout a prototype.  So i would recommend using the google .net client library for the YouTube api part it will just be easer then making a custom login for the auth part.